# Somar horas de todos funcionarios durante o mes

Tags: php, sql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP e MySQL onde uma pessoa faz algumas horas extras durante o mês.

```
pessoa = id - 5 - int /nome - 15 - varchar /

boletins = id -5 - int / idpessoa - 5 - int / horaextra - time / data - date /
```

Gostaria de gerar um relatório somando a hora extra de todos durante todo o mês, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
SELECT time_format( SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( horaextra ) ) ),'%H:%i:%s') AS horaextra FROM boletins where idpessoa = (numero do id, mas queria listar todos com a hora somada do mes inteiro)
```

Comment: Utilize a cláusula GROUP BY idpessoa e a função de agregação SUM e como condição o mês/ano desejado.

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
SELECT pessoa.nome, TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(boletins.horaextra))), '%H:%i:%s') AS horaextra 
FROM pessoa INNER JOIN boletins ON (pessoa.id = boletins.idpessoa)
WHERE MONTH(boletins.data) = mês_desejado AND YEAR(boletins.data) = ano_desejado
GROUP BY pessoa.nome;
```

ou algo parecido, de acordo com o SGBD utilizado.